# how do i render an actual a6 paper size in R Bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

Hi I am trying to render a book in R bookdown- and have installed all the prereqs. The standard pdf rendering is a4. I am trying to render it to a6 which is closer to a published book format rather than a handbook of size a4.

Below is my index.rmd

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Lyndon Sundmark"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
papersize: a6paper
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
# url: your book url like https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown
# cover-image: path to the social sharing image like images/cover.jpg
description: |
  This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book.
  The HTML output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook,
  set in the _output.yml file.
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
---
```

AND

Below is  my output.yml

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit: https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/edit/BRANCH/%s
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: header.tex
  number_sections: yes
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 3
  papersize: a6
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

When I render the pdf it still creates 8.5 by 11 inches.

How do I force it to re-layout content to a6 size?

Thanks for any help in advance...

Most google searches so far continue to point back to papersize as the key- but they dont seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Setting `papersize` in the YAML of `index.Rmd` should be fine. I think that `a6paper` is not a valid option since bookdown glues the value passed to `papersize` and `paper` and then sets the result as the document class in the header of the `tex` document that is compiled to PDF.

So `papersize: a6paper` yields

```tex
\documentclass[
  a6paperpaper,
]{book}
```

Using `papersize: a6` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I've found is to include a preamble.tex file with the following:

```
% DEFINE PHYSICAL DOCUMENT SETTINGS HD
% media settings
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.13in, paperheight=5.83in]{geometry}
\geometry{left=.5in}
\geometry{right=.5in}
\geometry{bottom=.75in}
\geometry{top=.75in}
```

The geometry measurements are the margins.